# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'coastlines'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray, cartopy

```
ds_mm=gb.mean(dim='TIME')
ds_mm
```

Data description is given here:
[image: preview of xarray Dataset with one variable ILD_T05 with dimensions (month, LAT71_110, LON86_140)]

```
ax= plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
pp=ds_mm.ILD_T05
p=pp.plot.contourf(   
    x='LON86_140',
    y='LAT71_110',
    col='month',
    levels=30,
    col_wrap=3,
    cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
)

for ax in p.axes.flat:
    ax.coastlines()
```

I am getting the contour plots correctly but while trying to add `coastlines` through a for loop it shows `attribute error.`

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\souga\OneDrive\Desktop\Python programs\gb.ipynb Cell 8 in <cell line: 12>()
      3 p=pp.plot.contourf(   
      4     x='LON86_140',
      5     y='LAT71_110',
   (...)
      9     cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
     10 )
     12 for ax in p.axes.flat:
---> 13     ax.coastlines()

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'coastlines'
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When asking a question, [please do not upload images of code, data, or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). Instead, you can copy the string representation of the object, e.g. `print(ds_mm)`, and paste it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) - that way, the contents are searchable, can be updated, and can be read by assistive devices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not created the contour plots on axes with the cartopy projection. To do this, use the `subplot_kws` argument to [`xr.DataArray.plot`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.plot.html#xarray-dataarray-plot), e.g.:

```py
pp=ds_mm.ILD_T05
p=pp.plot.contourf(   
    x='LON86_140',
    y='LAT71_110',
    col='month',
    levels=30,
    col_wrap=3,
    cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
    subplot_kws={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()},

)
```